# RESTful API best practices on endpoint design

Tags: api, rest

Let's say I'd like to implement two functions:

1. Register for a course
2. Pay the course fee

I understood that I might have two RESTful API endpoints like this

1. register the course for the student:
   send POST request to /myapp/api/students/{id}/courses
   with request body like

   {
   "course_id": 26,
   "is_discount": true,
   "reg_date": "2020-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
   }
2. create payment record of the student for the course:
   send POST request to /myapp/api/payment-records
   with request body like

   {
   "student_id": 204,
   "course_id": 26,
   "amount": 500
   }

My question is, how this can be done in one action (or within one transaction) from client side by just calling to one RESTful endpoint without separating them into two like the above? Because if one fails to make successful payment, due to network failure of card system, for example, then the course registered by the student should be rollbacked accordingly.

Or, should I do it like:
send POST request to /myapp/api/course-registration
with request body like this?

```
{
  course:  {
    "course_id": 26,
    "is_discount": true,
    "reg_date": "2020-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
  },
  payment: {
    "record_id": 1,
    "student_id": 204,
    "course_id": 26,
    "amount": 500
  }
}
```

Comment: This question basically asks about UX and design, as answer depends on what user behaviour is expected and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how this can be done in one action (or within one transaction) from client side by just calling to one RESTful endpoint without separating them into two like the above?

How would you do it on the web?

You'd have a web page with a form to collect all of the information you need from the student -- some fields might be pre-filled in, others might be "hidden" so that they aren't part of the presentation.  When the form is submitted, the browser would collect all of that information into a single `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` document, and would include that document in a POST request that targets whatever URI was specified by the form.

Note that you might also have two smaller forms - perhaps part of the same web page, perhaps somewhere else, to do the registration and payment separately.

Two things to note about the target URI.  The browser does not care what the spelling of the target-uri is; it's just going to copy that information into the HTTP request.  But the browser *does* care if the target URI is the same as something that is available in its local cache; see the specification of [invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) in RFC 7234.

So a heuristic that you might use for choosing the target is to think about which cached document must be refreshed if the POST is successful, and use the identifier for that document as the target-uri.